# CentOS 7, php script via apache doesn't resolve host names. If I use ip directly it works

Tags: php, apache, dns, centos, resolution

I've installed a LAMP stack over CentOS 7.

If I try to resolve a name via php from command line it works, but if I execute that script thru web server it doesn't resolve the name. If I use ip directly it works, in each case.

For example:

```
$ip = gethostbyname('www.google.com');    
echo "GOOGLE IP = " . $ip;  // it shows IP only via php-cli, not thru apache
```

Any idea?

EDIT: disabling SE enforcing it works. It would be useful to know how configure it to work with SE enforcement enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set SELinux to permissive

`setenforce 0`

Make sure selinux-policy, selinux-policy-devel, setroubleshoot-server, setroubleshoot are installed

`yum install selinux-policy, selinux-policy-devel, setroubleshoot-server, setroubleshoot -y`

then tail the messages file and grep for sealert

`tailf /var/log/messages | grep sealert`

Your SELinux problem will get spit out in the form of

```
hostname setroubleshoot: SELinux is preventing httpd (httpd_t) "getattr" to /var/www/html/file1 (samba_share_t). For complete SELinux messages. run sealert -l 84e0b04d-d0ad-4347-8317-22e74f6cd020
```

so you then just run `sealert -l 84e0b04d-d0ad-4347-8317-22e74f6cd020` to view your SELinux issue

Once you think you have fixed the issue, re enable SELinux `setenforce 1` and check to see if your problem is fixed. If not then repeat the steps.

More info on sealert can be found at [Red Hat's website](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/SELinux_Users_and_Administrators_Guide/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Troubleshooting-Fixing_Problems.html#sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Fixing_Problems-sealert_Messages), just don't disable SELinux.